# Laravel nova / add second login

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Im creating a Website with Laravel nova. When installing nova by default you get a login, a users table and a dashboard. Now I need to add a second login for another Tabel user_b. Is this possible and how ca I do it? Is there a way to edit and customize the components in the vendor/laravel/nova folder?

Comment: Why would you need a second login for another user table?

Comment: Because the client wants a login for his employees -> adminpanel, but also one for his clients -> clientpanel

Comment: So, why not do this based on roles, then you would need only one table. Or before the redirect you check if user should be admin or client and redirect them accordingly.

Comment: Because the clients_users have much more information that belongs into the databse table than the regular employees have. Also the the clients_users table should be a resource later on in the adminpanel

Comment: Yes i understand but you could make those fields nullable and only add data if the user is a client_user. And for the adminpanel you could just get all users from the table that are not admins but clients. Same output as all users from client_table.

Comment: Okay, I think your are right, I will build the logic with roles.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have admins table. You need to add a guard first.

In `config/auth.php` update guards and providers like this.

```php
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],
```

If you have `admins` table you need a model. So create model `Admin`. `php artisan make:model Admin` and you need to modify it like this;

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Nova\Auth\Impersonatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use AuthenticationLoggable;
    use Impersonatable;
  

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'permissions' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

In your `config/nova.php` change guard to `admin`

```
 'guard' => 'admin',
```

And your seperate login process implemented to nova.